# I m getting below error when i m using scrollGesture code from appium doc

Tags: android-gesture

The method of(K, V, K, V, K, V, K, V, K, V) in the type ImmutableMap is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, String, int, String, int, String, int, String, String, String, double)

The above error meesage it is showing and code mentioned below

```
    boolean canScrollMore = true;
    
    while(canScrollMore) {
        canScrollMore = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: scrollGesture", ImmutableMap.of(
                "left", 100, "top", 100, "width", 200, "height", 200,
                "direction", "down",
                "percent", 3.0
            ));
    
    System.out.println(canScrollMore);
    }
```

Please help to over come